# Get contents of a file served with Content-Disposition in PHP

Tags: php, curl, content-disposition

I'm trying to get the contents of a remote file using cURL or file_get_contents, but since the file is served using Content-Disposition, it seems that I only get the source of the webpage instead of the iCal file I actually want.
The URL I want to fetch is: http://afvalkalender.eindhoven.nl/Afvalkalender/download_ical.php?p=5621%20AJ&h=32

Hopefully one of you knows how to do this, cause searching on SO or Google only pointed me to ways to serve a file with Content-Disposition, however that is not what I'm looking for.

Comment: When I access the address you posted, I get a page that says 'AdressenResult is not valid'.

Comment: The address you provided does not point to a dynamically generated ical file. It's an error page of some sort.

Comment: It used to work here, but now it doesn't. I reckon it has something to do with a cookie. I'll investigate some more, if that's it, I'll close this question.